# Importing variable from one script to another: NameError: name 'XXXX' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, compiler-errors

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
#####Something
with ###something else###;
    #####Something more#####
    for ##something###:
        if ##something:
            pass
        else:
            Results = #something
```

I have a script a.py(above). my goal is to print 'Results' in a scrolled text box in the tkinter script below.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import os
from a import *

root = Tk()

##building frame, buttons and scrolled text box###

txt.insert(0.0, a.Results) #NameError: name 'a' is not defined
txt.grid(column=0,row=15)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is my my attempt to build a gui and output 'Results' but the NameError: name 'a' is not defined

What am I missing?

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you define `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Now I see your problem. When you use a `from a import *` it imports everything from `a` directly into your namespace. This means that instead of using `a.Results` you should just use `Results`. If you want to keep it in the `a` namespace you can `import a` instead.

Comment: Tried that but now  "name 'Results' is not defined"

Comment: @defjamvan Sounds like you aren't understanding modules in general. I would recommend giving [this a read](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm), or at least the **Packages in Python** section.